# How to execute specified test suites in boost.test library

Tags: unit-testing, testing, boost, test-suite

I am using Boost.Test library for implementing unit test cases in C++. Suppose I have two suites such as

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(TestA)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(CorrectAddition)
{
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(2+2, 4);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(WrongAddition)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(2 + 2, 5);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(TestB)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(CorrectAddition)
{
bool ret = true;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(ret, true);
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(WrongAddition)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(2 + 2, 5);
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

and I would like to run only say suite 'TestB', how shall I execute it. 
I really thank for your time and help. Sorry if this question is been posted or documented else where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the library-supplied main entry point, command-line parsing, etc., and haven't rolled your own, you can select specific test suites and test cases by name or pattern via a command-line switch at run time.

See [this page in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html) for a good example.

Comment: Would be nice if there was some hint of the steps required to get to the "example" part. Or is that some kind of sacred treasure that must be hidden like chronic masturbation disorder tendency ?

Answer (score 6):

Conform to this [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html), the OP should call the unit test executable with the following parameter

```
--run_test=TestB
```

to run only the unit tests of test suite `TestB`.

If the unit test `CorrectAddition`  of all test suites shall be run, then the parameter is

```
--run_test=*/CorrectAddition
```

Wildcard ability of Boost.Test is quite powerful, hence the parameter could also be written as

```
--run_test=*/C*
```