# How to set which Boost unit test to run

Tags: c++, unit-testing, program-entry-point, boost-test

I am trying to use boost-test, and in particular boost unit testing.

I clearly don't understand how is the main function generated and called, all the tutorial says is to define a module and write a test

`#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE EnfTraderTest`

`BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(CalculateExpectedPriceTest){BOOST_ERROR("Oops");}`

But, how do I say to my program to run this test ? I already have main function, I would like to decide to run the test or not, from my main function.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/963158/232490?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute test suites based on requirement in boost.test library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615979/how-to-execute-test-suites-based-on-requirement-in-boost-test-library)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to write your tests into one `.cpp`-file, and define the macro `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` before you include `unit_test.hpp`. You can then compile that `.cpp`-file and execute it. If you have tests in several `.cpp`-files, just link them all together, but take care that either `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` or `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` are defined in exactly one of them.

You can use the command-line parameter [`run_test`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html)  to only run a subset of tests, the default is to run all tests.

Comment: A note on `run_test`: if you use wildcards (e.g. `--run_test=*foo*`), depending on your shell, you may need to escape the wilcards (e.g. `--run_test=\*foo\*`). That just happened to me with `zsh`.